# Storing links supplied by users PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, security, url, user-input, sanitization

What is the best or safest way to handle user supplied urls. I'm looking to take urls to people social media sites; twitter, google+, facebook, youtube etc. I want to be able to take these url's and store them within my database without risk to the database, or the website.

What are my options? Do I filter the input and escape/exclude characters, do I only accept a partial url?

I've still uncertain of the best way to filter these links safely, I was thinking of a system that compares the user supllied link against an array of acceptable formats

ie.

my facebook link is https://www.facebook.com/lilbugga, but I can also use https://www.facebook.com/532850510.

Straight away thats 2 different variations, then poeple could also try to submit the link to their profile with http, https, www, no www etc etc

How do I handle all these different possible variations in format, do I create an array with the muliple different formats of link stored within it, to compare the user supplied string against?

Comment: I'm still looking for help if anyones out there, I've edited my orignal question to give some more detail in the hope it might help me find the type of answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The big risk with URLs is not what they contain ( which you can sanitise just the same as any other data coming in to your system ) but *where they go.* Your concern should be related to sending your users through a redirect that leads to malware infections, phishing sites and so on. Also finding ways to filter out spam as much as possible- any exposed web page which can accept input will become a guaranteed target for spammers, no matter how obscure, so you will need to think about that in your design.

You might want to look at something like [the Safe Browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/) from Google ( I'm sure other alternatives exist ) as a way of identifying potentially problematic URLs before you put them live.

Comment: That makes for an interesting read, I assume sanitizing URL's is going to be more complex than standard user input because they often contain obscure characters like % / _ ? = etc and allowing them poses some risk

Comment: Not really - you need to encode out anything that will put your database at risk anyways ( the best way to do this is usually through parameterised queries, but it depends on your platform ) and as long as your encoding and decoding happens symetrically, it shouldn't matter what unusual characters are in there because they will be decoded back on the way out.